# Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-graphql-tag' when running App with React Native 0.59.1

Tags: react-native, graphql

I ran into that strange issue after upgrading to React Native 0.59.1 and trying to run my app on iOS devices in xcode.

> ```
> Loading dependency graph, done.
> error: bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-graphql-tag' from '/Users/me/react_projects/my-app'
> - If you want to resolve "graphql-tag", use "module:graphql-tag"
> ```

I tried to install some potentially missing packages but it does not help. I can post my package.json if that helps.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you just changed your react-native and react versions in your package.json file .. .and npm installed them only ?

Comment: I made all the changes in rn-diff-purge too.

Comment: if you are using `.babelrc` change that to `babel.config.js` and add `"module:graphql-tag"` as plugins.

Comment: can you try using this command ```react-native start --reset-cache```